# How do I draw box-and-pointer diagrams?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

How do I draw box-and-pointer diagrams?  For example, I'd like to illustrate what happens when you manipulate nodes in a linked list.  Can I use MathJax?

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example:

$$
\newcommand{ptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
\begin{align*}
                                             &\mathtt{newNode} \\
                                             &\quad\downarrow  \\
\mathtt{head} \ptr{} \fbox{first} \ptr{next} &\fbox{another} \ptr{next} \mathtt{null} \\
                                             &\fbox{second}  \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{rest}    \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{of}      \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{list}    \ptr{next} \mathtt{null}
\end{align*}
$$

```
$$
\newcommand{ptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
\begin{align*}
                                             &\mathtt{newNode} \\
                                             &\quad\downarrow  \\
\mathtt{head} \ptr{} \fbox{first} \ptr{next} &\fbox{another} \ptr{next} \mathtt{null} \\
                                             &\fbox{second}  \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{rest}    \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{of}      \ptr{next}
                                              \fbox{list}    \ptr{next} \mathtt{null}
\end{align*}
$$
```

The key elements are:

- To get the \$\mathtt{typewriter}\$ font: `\mathtt{the text}`
- To create a \$\fbox{box}\$: `\fbox{box}`
- To draw an arrow \$\longrightarrow\$: `\longrightarrow`
- To label the arrow \$\overset{\mathtt{label}}{\longrightarrow}\$: `\overset{\mathtt{label}}{\longrightarrow}`
- To reduce code repetition, define a `\ptr{label}` command:

  ```
  \newcommand{ptr}[1]{\overset{\mathtt{#1}}{\longrightarrow}}
  ```
- To make it span multiple lines:

  ```
  \begin{align*}
      first line &alignmentpoint something something \\
      next line &alignmentpoint stuff \\
      third line &alignmentpoint stuff
  \end{align*}
  ```

Comment: See also: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on Meta.Math.SE.

Comment: gah, why is there MathJax but no syntax highlighting on Meta? If `<!-- language: lang-tex -->` worked here, this would be more readable :/

Answer (score 10):

I think it could be worth mentioning that http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw can be a nice picture-based alternative to the almighty MathJax, for perhaps simpler diagrams:

> ```
> [Customer]<>-orders*>[Order]
> [Order]++-0..*>[LineItem]
> [Order]-[note:Aggregate root.]
> ```

[image]

Comment: I love yUML \*-\*

Comment: Don't forget about the good old `mspaint.exe`! (It comes with free-hand circles!)

Comment: Just a note: on my work computer I can't see any images linked in questions/answers on SE, but math jax works just fine.  For people like me, it's always a pleasure to see math jax used on a programming SE instead of `enter image description here` - the alt-text of the image.

Answer (score 6):

http://asciiflow.com/ !

```
                    +-------------------+                     
                    |TimerQueue (static)|                     
                    +-------+-----------+                     
                            |                                 
+-----------+        +------v-------+          +-------------+
|TimerHolder+-------->TimerQueueTime+---------->TimerCallback|
+-----^-----+        +--------------+          +-----+-------+
      |                                              |        
      |                                              |        
  +---+-+                                        +---v----+   
  |Timer<----------------------------------------+Cyclical|   
  +-----+                                        +--------+
```

It is too bad that since a few weeks they nag you for 3 dollars ;\

Answer (score 5):

It's almost a duplicate of @Mat's Mug answer, but there is also [Scruffy](https://github.com/aivarsk/scruffy) that is an open-source desktop application designed to create yUML-like diagrams with a yUML-like syntax.

Morevoer, it also introduces some extensions to the yUML syntax and provides some basic support for [sequence diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram):

[image: yUML-like sequence diagram. That rocks!]

We really need to embed such a tool on some StackExchange sites. It would be priceless :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), possibly through its online version, [GraphViz Workspace](http://graphviz-dev.appspot.com/).

For example:

```
digraph {
  node [ shape = box ];

  a -> b;
  b -> c;
  c -> d1;
  c -> d2;
}
```

[image: rendered result of the code above]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) (a desktop application). I especially like its grid mode, which allows you to position the boxes exactly the way you want, while keeping them evenly spaced.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this with tikz; see for example the question I just posted on tex.stackexchange:

[image]

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201071/how-do-i-make-tikz-circular-arrowheads-concentric-to-the-point-they-connect